# Prevent Android 13 from showing the notification permission prompt

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-push-notification, android-13

Android 13 automatically asks the user if they would like to allow the app to send them notifications.

My app does not show any notifications, therefore it doesn't make any sense to ask the user for push notifications at this time. I would like to defer this prompt for when we actually have notifications and a well defined permissions UX.

How do you tell Android 13 to *not* ask for the permission automatically?

Comment: Removing the permission from the manifest might be the only option.

Comment: Show the notification permission prompt may be more user-friendly, It is also the trend of the future Android version 

see https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#request-in-context

Comment: @MartinZeitler I actually dont have that permission declared in the manifest at all

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have 3 different Ionic+Capacitor apps exhibiting the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My app does not show any notifications

Something — perhaps a library — is doing something related to notifications, such as setting up a notifications channel. That will trigger the notification permission prompt.

IOW, the existence of that prompt means that *something* is working with notifications. You can tell this by creating a scrap "Hello, world!" project in your IDE, running it on your Android 13 device, and noticing that the notification permission prompt does not appear.

> How do you tell Android 13 to not ask for the permission automatically?

Remove the code that is working with notifications. For example, you might check your app's page in Settings and see if any notification channels are set up, and see if their names help you identify what code is creating those channels.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade targetSdk and compileSdk to 33

If your notification feature is optional for users, you could [migrate apps to Android 13](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/migration) to control the timing of requesting [Notification runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#request-in-context) by yourself. (System won't auto ask for notification permission on android 13 devices)